# Limit number of accepted groupings

Tags: powerbi

A custom visual that I am creating for Power BI receives categories and values like this.

```js
dataRoles: [
    {
        name: 'Category',
        kind: VisualDataRoleKind.Grouping,
    },
    {
        name: 'Values',
        kind: VisualDataRoleKind.Measure,
    }],
```

Now for the moment I only want to use one category grouping. I found the [Tornado chart sample](https://app.powerbi.com/visuals/) that supports this nicely in the UI. When a second group is dropped it will replace the first instead of being added.

I believe this is achieved by setting `conditions` in `dataViewMappings` but I couldn't figure out how. This seems to have no effect:

```
conditions: [
    { 'Category': { max: 1 }, 'Values': { min: 0 } }
],
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Aster Plot capabilities](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/src/Clients/CustomVisuals/visuals/asterPlot/asterPlot.ts).  I think they do pretty much what you want. You might just need to set the min on 'Y' to 1 to match your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Looks like I added the conditions at the wrong position.